# Mysql group by and Left join an associated table PHP Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii2

I have two tables `order_products` and `order_product_tax` which has one to many relation. one order_products can have multiple order_product_tax

Here is the SQL fiddle for the two tables
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2608e

I need to get an output like this

```
[  
 {  
  "product_id":2809,
  "product_name":"Test Product1",
  "quantity":5,
  "amount":500,
  "taxes":[  
     {  
        "tax_id":47,
        "tax_name":"VAT",
        "tax_amount":21.14
     },
     {  
        "tax_id":48,
        "tax_name":"CST",
        "tax_amount":5.17
     }
  ]
 },
 {  
  "product_id":2810,
  "product_name":"Test Product2",
  "quantity":4,
  "amount":200,
  "taxes":[  
     {  
        "tax_id":47,
        "tax_name":"VAT",
        "tax_amount":12.57
     },
     {  
        "tax_id":48,
        "tax_name":"CST",
        "tax_amount":11.34
     }
  ]
 }
]
```

How I could get this result?

I am using PHP and Yii2 if that matters.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Edit: Yii2 models

OrderProduct

```
class OrderProduct extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

   public static function tableName()
   {
    return 'order_product';
   }


   public function rules()
   {
    return [
        [['product_id', 'order_id', 'quantity'], 'integer'],
        [['amount'], 'number'],
        [['product_name'], 'string', 'max' => 250],
    ];
   }

   public function getTaxes() {
    return $this->hasMany(OrderProductTax::className(),['order_product_id' => 'id']);
   }

   public function attributeLabels()
   {
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'product_id' => 'Product ID',
        'order_id' => 'Order ID',
        'product_name' => 'Product Name',
        'amount' => 'Amount',
        'quantity' => 'Quantity',
    ];
   }
}
```

OrderProductTax

```
class OrderProductTax extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

   public static function tableName()
   {
    return 'order_product_tax';
   }

   public function rules()
   {
    return [
        [['order_product_id', 'tax_id'], 'integer'],
        [['tax_amount'], 'number'],
        [['tax_name'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
    ];
   }

   public function attributeLabels()
   {
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'order_product_id' => 'Order Product ID',
        'tax_id' => 'Tax ID',
        'tax_name' => 'Tax Name',
        'tax_amount' => 'Tax Amount',
    ];
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the foreign key in order_products table ?

Comment: @Jon Ekiz if you look at the table fiddle there is 'id' fields which is auto increment for both table

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: @Insane Skull `SELECT 
op.product_id, op.product_name, op.quantity, SUM(op.amount) as amount, SUM(op.quantity) as quantity, opt.*
FROM order_product op left join order_product_tax opt on opt.order_product_id=op.id group by op.product_id`

This will not list all the tax but one. If anyone could help me to direct to what to do,it will be very helpful

Comment: This is very easy to do with Yii2. But can you just show us the models. This will help us explain this in a much easier way

Comment: @mrateb I added the models. the sample data and mysql tables are included here.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2608e

Comment: @RiyasKpYiideveloper see the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the SQL. you can use group concat to combine columns into json:

```
SELECT amounts.*
  ,GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{tax_id:"', tax_id, '", tax_name:"',tax_name,'", tax_amount:"',tax_amount,'"}'))
FROM
(
SELECT op.product_id, 
op.product_name, 
SUM(op.amount) as amount, 
SUM(op.quantity) as quantity
FROM order_product op 
group by 1,2
)amounts
LEFT JOIN 
(
select product_id
,tax_id
,tax_name
,sum(tax_amount) as tax_amount
from order_product op
join ordeR_product_tax opt
on op.id = opt.order_producT_id
group by 1,2,3
) taxes
on amounts.product_id = taxes.product_id
group by 1,2,3,4
```